# boundness about Fejer kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

let $F_N(x)$ denote the $N^\text{th}$  Fejer kernel.$$F_N(x)=\frac{1}{N}\frac{\sin^2(\frac{Nx}{2})}{\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})} \forall x\in[-\pi,\pi]/\{0\}$$
$$F_N(0)=N$$

now we have to show that there is some fixed $C>0$ such that for all $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$. $$F_N(x)\leq \min\{N,\frac{C}{Nx^2} \}$$

I have proved that $F_N(x)\leq \frac{\pi^2}{Nx^2}$ for all $x \in[-\pi,\pi]\setminus\{0\}$

but how to prove from here??
or there is some other way ??

Comment: Just evaluate the limit at $x=0$. That is the only point left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dirichlet kernel is
$$
              D_N(x) = \sum_{n=-N}^{N}e^{inx}
$$
The Fejer kernel $F_N$ is the average of the Dirichlet kernels $D_0,D_1,\cdots,D_{N-1}$.
$$
              F_N(x) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}D_n(x).
$$
So
\begin{align}
 |F_N(x)|&= \left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}e^{ikx}\right|\\
    & \le \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}1 \\
    & =\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(2n+1) \\
    & =\frac{1}{N}\left(2\frac{N(N-1)}{2}+N\right) = N.
\end{align}